# Angular 5: How to share the same instance of a service in the components of a lazy-loaded feature module?

Tags: angular, service, components, lazy-loading

I'm using Angular 5 and I created a feature-module with routing and configured it for lazy loading.
Now I'm at the point where I need to share the same instance of a service located inside the feature module, between two components inside the feature module, in order to pass an object from one component to the other after the user clicks on a router-link.

If I put the service I want to share, inside the providers array of the app.module.ts all works as I expect. However if I put the service in the providers array of the featureModule.module.ts it doesn't work.

Here the structure of the project:
[Questionnaires feature module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSHBd.png)

So in the end, is it possible to share the same instance of a service between the components of a feature module by just putting the service in the providers array of the feature-module, in this case within questionnaires.module.ts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make a service singleton using  ModuleWithProviders, you can define static forRoot that return ModuleWithProviders, your sharedService will have one instance in all lazy loaded modules

```
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
     return {
        ngModule: SharedModule,
        providers: [sharedService]
    }
  }
 }
```

and you can import your shared module using .forRoot inside your app.module and all lazy loaded module will have one instance

```
imports: [   
  SharedModule.forRoot()
],
```

Comment: So, I should create a new SharedModule with a SharedService, and in order to inject the SharedService in the components of a FeatureModule, I will have to import the SharedModule within the module of the FeatureModule. Is the flow correct?

Comment: i've updated the answer, you don't need to import it inside each module if you import it in app.module, and you have to use .forRoot()